# Is it safe to turn off Windows Firewall on private network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall

In windows firewall there got two options, one if for private network, and the other is for public network. As I am using CCProxy for my local network and it is suggesting to turn off firewall for private network and leave the public network on.

So, having setting which off on private network and on for public network will it protect my PC from thread from outside world? I mean, locally PC to PC we don't need firewall from each other, but only need it from the internet. The connection come from outside.

Thank you.

Comment: `I mean, locally PC to PC we don't need firewall from each other,` - Why do you assume that other systems on your network will never be infected/compromised?  Many times I have seen people with a portable computer bring malware into a network and cause chaos, because the systems on the network made the silly assumption that all local systems could be trusted.

Answer (score 3):

Although some would disagree, the Windows Firewall doesnt offer much protection.  If you are behind a firewall/router from your ISP, then there is no need for it.  Software firewalls, in general, or more of a nuisance than help.

Comment: I would tend to disagree on the point that if I take my laptop to a friend's house and connect to their network, I do not know if their network and computers have the necessary security that meets my standards. If there is a virus on their network that can spread easily internally, I open myself for risk by not having a local software firewall running on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to turn off Windows Firewall on a private network?

Obviously, that depends.  What private network, and what do you consider "safe"?

I would answer in three parts:

- If you are replacing Windows Firewall with [any superior product](https://www.techradar.com/news/the-best-free-firewall), then of course it is safe to turn off Windows Firewall after the other product is functioning.

  - This is the ideal solution, of course.
- If you are talking about if it is safe to have NO software firewall on private networks, then you need to think about it.

  - Since a Windows "private network" is whatever you tell Windows is a "private" network, what networks are you telling Windows are private?

    - How secure are they?
    - How do you know how secure they are?
    - Why do you think of their current level as "secure" for those that qualify?
    - If any of that is "because the other people/machines on the network don't do anything too risky", then mark their network as "insecure".  Popup advertisements with zero day exploits can hit any computer running any browser from any site, even sites you trust, since trusting them is NOT the same as trusting their advertising.
    - If you rate them secure because they have signficant network security infrastructure, including above consumer grade firewalls, IDS/IPS appliances, inline antimalware/antivirus, etc. etc., then that is you trusting their network over your own.  This can be valid, but is something to consider carefully - zero day exploits can hit ANYONE - KRACK, Heartbleed, Meltdown/Spectre, etc.
- Are you personally using a hardware firewall of your own on every "private" network?  If so, yes, I would generally say your hardware firewall would render Windows Firewall superfluous, if it's between your hardware and ALL other hardware.

### TL;DR: Security is all about layers

Security is about layers.  Every layer can be vulnerable to attacks; and, frankly, every layer WILL be vulnerable to attacks at some points in time, from your browser add-on to your CPU itself.  Having more and more layers allows you to have a far higher chance that not every layer is vulnerable during the same time window.

For instance, a normal household's layers will include:

- NAT from the ISP
- Consumer grade "router/firewall"

  - With NAT internally
  - With a default "admin" password, no firmware patches, and no-one monitoring its worthless logs.
- Wifi with WPA2-Personal using AES

  - With a default password provided by the ISP
  - Which has never had any patches
- Local LAN
- Your computer

  - Which may have a software firewall to limit incoming access
  - Which may have antivirus
  - Which may have other anti-malware
  - Whose logs no-one probably monitors

A more secure system would have:
- NAT from the ISP
- Midline to advanced firewall
   - Patched recently
   - Whose logs are monitored and/or which provides alerts
- IDS/IPS in IPS mode
   - Patched recently
   - with up to date signatures
- Inline antivirus/antimalware at the network level
   - with up to date signatures
- Wifi with WPA2-Personal with AES
   - With a long, random passphrase
   - Patched recently
   - Whose logs are monitored to see what devices are connecting
   - with client isolation turned on
- Local LAN
   - with VLANs segregating traffic
- Your device (as above)

Comment: "If you are replacing Windows Firewall with any superior product, then of course it is safe to turn off Windows Firewall after the other product is functioning."

Most of the supposedly "superior" products actually just use the windows firewall on the back end. Turning of windows firewall thus turns of their protection as well. The reason for this, btw, is because windows firewall is actually *very good* and it's hard to make meaningful improvements on it. Just a more user-friendly UI... mostly.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that if you know your private network is safe then its no big deal. However, you may want to turn it on while connecting to friends' and family's private networks as there's no telling what could be wreaking havoc on their end.